# autofill with data from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

On one sheet I have a list of items in the first column with pertinent data in the next several adjacent cells. On another sheet I want all the pertinent data to auto transfer to a row when I type in one of the items in the first cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VLOOKUP formula to retrieve data from the first sheet to the second sheet automatically. The VLOOKUP formula searches for a specified item in the first column of the first sheet and retrieves the corresponding values from the adjacent cells.

Here's an example of how to use VLOOKUP to auto-fill data from Sheet1 to Sheet2:

1. In Sheet2, enter the item you want to look up in the first cell of the row where you want the data to be auto-filled.
2. In the adjacent cells of the same row, enter the following formula (assuming the data in Sheet1 is in columns A to E):
   `=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:E, 2, FALSE)`
   `=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:E, 3, FALSE)`
   `=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:E, 4, FALSE)`
   `=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:E, 5, FALSE)`

This formula searches for the value in cell A1 (the item you want to look up) in the first column of Sheet1 (column A) and retrieves the data in the corresponding cells in columns B, C, D, and E.

3. Drag the formula across the adjacent cells to auto-fill the data for all the columns you need.

Note that if you add more rows or columns to Sheet1, you'll need to adjust the range in the VLOOKUP formula to include the new data. Alternatively, you can use a structured table reference in the VLOOKUP formula to automatically expand and contract the data range as it changes.